# Forcing ld to bind to unversioned .so file

Tags: linux, ld

Can I force `ld` to link against an unversioned .so file?

Under linux, when I link a C++ program to a shared library, it will be bound to the versioned .so file, which is normally a very good idea. For example, if I compile my program with

```
g++ main.cxx -l somelib
```

and then check

```
ldd ./a.out
```

it will print something like

```
libsomelib.so.1 => /xxxx/somelib/libsomelib.so.1
```

Because of a system broken elsewhere, this file is installed in a target as `libsomelib.so` instead of, as normal, as `libsomelib.so.1` with symlink. It is not possible for me to change this, so as a workaround I would like to change my makefile to link against the unversioned .so file. (Binary compatibility is not a problem here, since everything is in a controlled environment).

Comment: can't you make a symlink from libsomelib.so to libsomelib.so.1 on the target system? this simlink can reside under the application directory (set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before launching).

Comment: I can probably hack the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it will be quite complicated, but I was hoping there was some ld magic I could do to rewrite the dependency...

Answer (score 1):

From reading the ld manual, this does not appear to be possible. I recommend using patchelf to fix it up after the fact, e.g., `patchelf --replace-needed libsomelib.so.1 libsomelib.so a.out`. Note that the latest released version of patchelf 0.9 is buggy, you will need to compile patchelf master from source to get a working implementation of `--replace-needed`.